# Why is Google Translate API giving me different results on certain machines?

Tags: google-translate

I am using the Google Translate API to do some translations. When I give it the parameters

```
    {
        'source': 'de',
        'target': 'en,
        'q': 'Die schön <span>löwen</span> geht zum Wald',
        'format': 'html'
    }
```

it gives the following result on Travis CI and a VPS of mine:

```
The <span>beautiful lion</span> goes to the forest
```

Locally, on my development machines it translates to:

```
The beautiful <span>lion</span> goes to the forest
```

Why am I getting different result on different machines? Does the origin of the request matter? And if so, why?

Comment: Note, a correct version of that german sentence would be "Die schöne <span>Löwen</span> gehen zum Wald" (plural), or alternatively "Die schöne <span>Löwin</span> geht zum Wald" (singular).

I can also say that the result on the development machine is the correct one. Where the differerence comes from is very peculiar though...

Comment: Did anyone ever find an answer to this? I just posted here https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/45503/google-translate-provides-two-different-translations-of-the-same-word-in-differe. I'm seeing the same problem but in two web browsers on the same host! In my case, when I hit Google Translate with Selenium it gives me the wrong translation but it's fine if I type it in manually.

Comment: As an additional test, I had Selenium type the request into Google as if it were a human. It seems to be a difference between Selenium and an actual browser. It does the same whether I use Selenium with Chrome or Selenium with Firefox